# Initialization array of object with constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

How can we use constructor to initialize array of object. For example we have:

```
class K{
K(int i){}
};
int main(){
K* k = new K[10]; 
}
```

It makes compile error. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
K* k = new K[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

provided that your compiler supports this feature of the C++ 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Since the only applicable constructor of `class K` is the one taking an `int` the compiler cannot default-construct the elements in your newly allocated array, which is what it tries (and fails) in the following:

```
K * k = new K[10]; // 1. allocate memory for 10 elements
                   // 2. default these 10 elements them
```

The above would work if `K` had a default-constructor, ie. if it was defined as:

```
class K {
  K()      { /* ... */ } // <- default constructor
  K(int i) { /* ... */ }

  /* ... */
};
```

---

You have to explicitly initialize each and every element of the array using something as the below:

```
K * k = new K[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; // C++11
```

<sub>**Note:** if you don't have the pleasure of working in C++11 you cannot use the above solution, and  solutions where braced-initialization isn't available quickly becomes a mess.. easiest solution in that case is to add a default-constructor to `K`, or to use a `std::vector` and add one `K` element at a time (or using the copy-constructor of `K`.</sub>